# ScrollView does not fill the whole screen

Tags: android, layout, uiscrollview, scrollview

I'm trying to do a simple `SrcollView` in my android application. Unfortunately I cannot do that because the `SrcollView` doesn't fill the screen so the user can't see the bottom of the layout. Here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:id="@+id/relativeinfo1">

<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/titleinfo"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageinfo"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleinfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageinfo"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="phone"
    android:id="@+id/mooobil"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="phone"
    android:id="@+id/telefoneeo"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="email"
    android:id="@+id/emailese"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:id="@+id/honlapese"/>


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageinfo"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageinfo"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cimtext"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Cím: "
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>


<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/vonal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="#FFD700" />

<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/vonal2"
    android:background="#FFD700"/>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/relativemaplayout">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I can scroll down a little bit but more than half of the `Google Map` does not seem. Have you any idea how can I make the `ScrollView` fill the the whole screen including the map?

I have read a lot about this and yes I'm using `android:fillViewport="true"` but it's still wrong.

Comment: It is the issue I guess of putting google map in the view as map also have scrolling behaviour.  google out for scrolling of scrollview with google map like that..

Comment: android:layout_height="10dp" your RelativeLayout height is fix thats why map not shwoing